# ClassNotFoundException: io.grpc.internal.BaseDnsNameResolverProvider when trying to create a BigtableDataClient from Windows

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, google-cloud-bigtable

When spinning up a Spring boot application on Intellij, that tries to connect the GCP's BigTable, we get the following error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/internal/BaseDnsNameResolverProvider`

This is the stack trace:

```
...nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient]: Factory method 'bigtableDataClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/internal/BaseDnsNameResolverProvider
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1358) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
           ....
```

The import in Gradle is:

`implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigtable:1.13.0'`

**Update:**

I tried to specifically use a different `grpc-alt` version:

`compile group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-alts', version: '1.29.0'` 
But it did not help.

If I try to run the app from the Gradle command of `bootRun` it spins up with no problem. Only when trying to start it in the Intellij it faces the same issue.

Comment: This issue may be related: https://github.com/googleapis/java-pubsub/issues/217

Comment: Looks like some of the dependencies still uses the old `grpc` version. Please check also these comments: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7002#issuecomment-623778715 https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/7002#issuecomment-624187358 to list the dependency tree in project and to make sure 1.29 version is used everywhere. Then re-import project in IDE Gradle tool window.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround: use version 1.28.1 for all `grpc` components.

While there are other versions currently available (1.29.0, 1.30.0, 1.30.1, 1.30.2 per https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.grpc), they exhibit the same error – `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/internal/BaseDnsNameResolverProvider` – in my local tests.

Answer (score 0):

In my case explicitly adding

```
implementation group: 'io.grpc', name: 'grpc-core', version: "${grpcVersion}"
```

has helped.
(I was using grpcVersion 1.35.0)